# how to send JSON object with value key as parameters in http post request in IOS swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to create an HTTP post request to send a JSON object as `queryParam` but it's not helping me. I can easily send the request in Android through Retrofit but it does not work in iOS Swift.

I am receiving the JSON object in REST API like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
    @POST
    @Path("UpdateTenantProfiledetails")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Consumes("application/json")

public String UpdateTenantProfilem(@QueryParam("profileDetail") JSONObject profileDetail) throws JSONException { 
// code
}
```

I can easily give a key value in Android Retrofit like this:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST(AppConstants.SERVER_URL_EXT + "UpdateTenantProfile/UpdateTenantProfiledetails")
    Call<BeanGeneral> postEditProfile (@Query("profileDetail") JSONObject profileDetail);
```

I don't know how to give the `@QueryParam` (`profileDetail`) key in iOS Swift.
Can anyone help me to solve this, either it's through NSURL Session or Alamafire?

I'm trying in IOS through URLSession like this

```
let json = [ "PIDNO":self.defaults.value(forKey: "pidno") as? String ?? "" ,
                     "GENDER":self.gender!,
                     "TENANTNAME":self.txtTenantName.text ?? "",
                     "EMAIL":self.txtEmailId.text ?? "",
                     "OFFPHONE":self.officeMobile.text ?? "",
                     "MOBILE":self.txtMobile.text ?? ""
            ] as [String : String]
    
        _ =  ActivityIndicator.show("Loading...".localized(), disableUI: true)
        let url = SharedInstance.sharedInstance.url+"UpdateTenantProfile/UpdateTenantProfiledetails"
        let requestURL = NSURL(string:"\(url)")!
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL as URL)
        
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){ data,response,error in
```

On the server side I am getting `null` value.

In Postman it works like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nh7un.png)

Comment: It isn't clear exactly what you are trying to do. You can't put JSON into a query parameter - many of the characters are not legal in a query parameter. A `POST` consists of a URL, including optional query parameters, and a payload, which is usually in `JSON`. Edit your question to explain, in a language and platform agnostic way, what you need to put into your query parameters, and the source of the information.

Comment: Example: I need to submit a POST to xyz.com in the form `https://xyz/com/verb?foo=bar`, where the key `foo` and the value `bar` both come from a JSON payload received in a previous network request. the payload of the POST should be JSON containing `<describe your JSON payload>`

Comment: please check i updated, i am a beginner in IOS that's why i attach an example of android because through android i easily get it at bekend

Comment: You posted Android code, which most of us who know iOS don't understand. Then you posted your attempt on iOS, without telling us how it fails to meet your needs. Edit your question to explain what result you are after IN PLATFORM-AGNOSTIC TERMS, not using Android code. Then tell us how the iOS Swift code you posted fails to meet those needs.

Comment: on server side i am getting null value, not getting any JSONObject

Comment: Edit your question to say: What should your outgoing URL look like? Where should the values used to compose that URL come from? What should the payload to the POST contain?

Comment: hi I attach a picture of the service which perfectly works in postman